# Django: Supporting URL tag with quotes (>1.5) or without them (older Django versions)

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

Is there a way to support:

```
{% url myapp.views.index %}
```

and

```
{% url 'myapp.views.index' %}
```

both at the same time?

Why to do that? I was told to change all my dev environment to 1.6. which I did; however surprisingly the prod server still has django 1.4. Only big incompatibility is the URL tag.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you elaborate more about the use case and motivation? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. Why don't upgrade production to 1.6 and fix the url tags?

Comment: @alecxe Of course that would be the best idea but I have no full access to that server and people in charge are not at the office. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Load the future version of the url tag in your template, then you can use the new syntax in Django 1.3 or 1.4 as well.

```
{% load url from future %}
{% url 'myapp.views.index' %}
```

Loading the URL tag from future is deprecated in Django 1.7, and [removed in Django 1.9](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/releases/1.9/#features-removed-in-1-9). Once you have upgraded production to 1.5 or greater, you can remove it from your templates.